# ASMX with jquery works locally, but not when deployed to IIS 6.0

Tags: jquery, asmx

I have a simple jquery call that is trying to return some XML from an ASMX service. This call works locally, but after deploying the service and page with the .ajax() call on it, I get just "spinning" on the web service call.

I made sure that the ASPNET user account has the appropriate rights to access the folder where the ASMX rests. Also, I have added the following lines to the web.config before deploying to the server:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

When I bring this up in firebug to inspect the call I see the headers, but the post and response is nothing, it is just "spinning." I never get an error in return, I only get incessant spinning.

The html page and the web service are on the same domain (in the same folder even).

Thank you.

UPDATE: I have now read the Encosia article on adding [webmethod] to static methods on .aspx pages (i.e. default.aspx) ([link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)). I can now call these methods locally without an issue, but when I deploy to IIS 6.0 I get no response. This has taken the .asmx call out of the equation and I am left with something more fundamental. What configuration section am I missing to allow any $.ajax() operation to a local page work?

Answer (score 1):

your version my vary:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

You might also do a compare of the files on local and the deployed server as there are other parts of the web.config that are needed.

EDIT: just checking, but did you wrap your addition, and allow JSON(assumption you use that):

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCaching="true" enableCompression="true" />
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```